# opm pruning all the version of the catalog from the image

Tags: openshift, redhat

I am pruning opm index with the custom catalog that i require but wheni do that i get all the versions of the image. How do i get only the latest image version and not all\

```
 ./opm index prune \
    -f registry.redhat.io/redhat/redhat-operator-index:v4.6 \
    -p openshift-pipelines-operator-rh \
    --generate
```

Result :

```
openshift-pipelines-operator.v1.0.1
openshift-pipelines-operator.v1.1.1
redhat-openshift-pipelines-operator.v1.1.2
redhat-openshift-pipelines-operator.v1.2.0
redhat-openshift-pipelines-operator.v1.2.1
redhat-openshift-pipelines-operator.v1.2.2
redhat-openshift-pipelines-operator.v1.2.3
```

but what i want is the latest version from the result that is

```
openshift-pipelines-operator.v1.1.1
redhat-openshift-pipelines-operator.v1.2.3
```